# Error while trying to serialise Google NLP API Response using Protobuf using Python

Tags: python, serialization, google-cloud-platform, nlp, protocol-buffers

I am trying to pass the response of Google's NLP API to Google's Protobuf on my GCP VM. I keep getting the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/scrapers_v3/utils/google_nlp.py", line 53, in get_entities_from_text
    element = json_format.MessageToDict(entity)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 168, in MessageToDict
    return printer._MessageToJsonObject(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 204, in _MessageToJsonObject
    return self._RegularMessageToJsonObject(message, js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 240, in _RegularMessageToJsonObject
    js[name] = self._FieldToJsonObject(field, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 282, in _FieldToJsonObject
    if field.file.syntax == 'proto3':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'syntax'
```

The value `entity` is an element of `[json_format.MessageToDict(entity) for entity in response.entities]`.

Interestingly the same code runs properly on my local machine.

- google-cloud-language version: 1.0.2
- Protobuf version: 3.10.0

Comment: What endpoint of the GCP NLP API are you calling?

Comment: ```client = language.LanguageServiceClient()```

```document = language.types.Document(content=text, type=language.enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)```

```response = client.analyze_entities(document=document, encoding_type=encoding, retry=RETRY)```

```return [json_format.MessageToDict(entity) for entity in response.entities]```

Comment: The issue seems to be related to "if field.file.syntax == 'proto3' " Please share your code until that point :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this [post](https://intellipaat.com/community/22100/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something) about `AttributeErrors` messages, maybe you should re-check the proto object to be serialized